# Do Indian Citizens need a Cuban Transit Visa to change Terminals?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, cuba, hav

I am an Indian Citizen and will be arriving at Havana airport's Terminal 3 and will be taking a separate onward flight to Cayman Islands from Terminal 2. Can anyone tell if I would need a Transit visa or a Tourist card to transfer from Terminal 3 to 2 along with the baggage?

Answer (score 6):

As you are holding an onwards ticket you will be granted entry into Cuba for 72 hours to allow for you to make your next flight. You will be able to leave Terminal 2 to go outside of the airport and transfer onto Terminal 3. Or, anywhere else in the country during your 72 hour period as long as you are back to take your next flight.

> You can enter Cuba, but your transit cannot last more than 72 hours
>   from your hour of arrival. ([source](https://www.ivisa.com/cuba-blog/what-is-the-cuba-visa-policy))

Also confirmed by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b), the database used by airline employees:

> Visa required, except for Holders of confirmed onward tickets

Please ensure you have a visa for the Cayman Islands.

Comment: Yes, I do have necessary documents for an onward travel to Cayman Islands. The other Question I have is, can I step out of the airport as my layover at Cuba Airport is 20hrs?

Comment: @yms do I need a visa to go from Terminal 3 to 2 in that case?

Comment: @Aleem You do not need a visa, I have edited my answer to make it clearer :)

Comment: @Uciebila according to user named yms replied in this section that I would be exiting the airport to get from terminal 3 to terminal 2. Which might attract a visa he says..

Comment: @Aleem The Answer posted by Uciebilia is clear that because you have an onward ticket, you do not need a visa to transit in Cuba as long as your stay is less than 72 hours; two independent sources are cited in support. Then you write "Which might attract a visa he says." The earlier answer that said a visa might be required was wrong, and has been deleted. You should ignore it.